# C# Binary CmdLet this.MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot is empty

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing a C# cmdlet to install and uninstall various products in a standardized way via a script. This includes a log file (via NLog) that is created and filled at runtime. PSScriptRoot and ScriptName are listed in the header of the log file and is also needed in other steps.

I thought I could use *this.MyInvocation* for this, but unfortunately the object is always empty.

Here's an example:

```
namespace MyCmdlet
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Update, "Environment")]
    [OutputType(typeof(UpdateEnvironment))]
    public partial class UpdateEnvironment : PSCmdlet
    {
    # Some parameters

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            base.ProcessRecord();
            string currentTime   = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
            string toReturn      = string.Empty;
            InvocationInfo iInfo = this.MyInvocation;

            // For testing
            var a = PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot;

            // Should be filled
            GlobalProps.psScriptRoot = this.MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot;
            GlobalProps.psScriptName = this.MyInvocation.ScriptName;
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

How do I test? -

- In Visual Studio → *Project* → *Setting* → *Debugging*, I start an external program ("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe") and in the start options I add these arguments: -noexit -command "&{ import-module .\MyCmdlets.dll -verbose}"
- After starting, I fill in some variables for testing in the current opened PowerShell console
- Finally I call my cmdlet.

Other tests...

- [PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise) → *[Import-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)* → *...
- PowerShell console → *Import-Module* → ...

...has the same effect. MyInvocation.PSSCriptRoot, ScriptName, ... are empty. How can I use this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK! I have found a solution!

InvocationInfo is processed correctly. But only 1x. Now I save the information in a static variable and then only work with it.

Comment: What do you mean by *"But only 1x"*? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62303852/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).